# checkable menu items

Tags: contextmenu

i  have a contextmenu. how can i make it checkable?

System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem does not contain a definition for IsCheckable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it already is checkable. At least according to msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischeckable%28v=VS.85%29.aspx